# -bash: ls: command not found at Terminal on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash, unix, terminal

I need to start using GIT for my projects from now on and I need to use some UNIX commands. but no matter what I do, I always receive "command not found" error.

I installed MacPorts, but still cant run any UNIX command :/

When I try `$ ls`, I get the error below, same for `sudo`, or any other command:

```
-bash: ls: command not found
```

and when I try `$PATH`, I get the lines below:

```
hakan-yilmaz-MacBook-Pro:~ hakanyilmaz$ **$PATH**

-bash: /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/opt/subversion/bin/:PATH: No such file or directory
```

I'm on Mac OS X 10.6.6

I spent 2-3 days and kept Googling and trying everything I found at forums, but no success.

---

**SOLUTION:**

I opened `.bash_profile` and removed everything else than

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Then, I reboot that Mac, and it works!

Comment: Consider copying your solution from your question and adding it as an answer (or accepting an existing answer) so other people know how you fixed your problem.

Comment: If you wish, instead of using textwrangler and navigate to the hidden files on finder, you may also use the absolute path of pico for example, by doing, inside your profile file directory, the following: `$~ /usr/bin/pico .bash_profile`.

Answer (score 9):

Your `$PATH` was overwritten by MacPorts in error. This is my `$PATH` with MacPorts installed, you should edit it accordingly and set it in your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`.

```
blackcomb:~ tyson$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

Specifically, you are missing `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, `/usr/sbin`, `/sbin`, `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/X11/bin`.